# Overleaf Error: "The font "Fira Math Bold" cannot be found" using provided cls file

Tags: fonts, fontspec, overleaf

I am writing my thesis using a template provided by school. The template is meant to be used locally (e.g. with TexStudio) but I'm using Overleaf with the XeLaTeX compiler.

When I compile the document I get one error :`Package fontspec Error: The font "Fira Math Bold" cannot be found.`.

The error points at this part in the .cls file of the template.

```
    % Use a unicode-compliant sans serif math font
    \IfFontExistsTF{Fira Math Regular}{%
        \setmathfont{Fira Math Regular}[BoldFont=Fira Math Bold]
        \setmathfont{Fira Math Regular}[FakeSlant, range={bfit->it}]
    }{%
        \setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular.otf}[
            Path = fonts/FiraMath/,
            BoldFont=FiraMath-Bold.otf]
        \setmathfont{FiraMath-Regular.otf}[
            Path = fonts/FiraMath/,
            FakeSlant,
            range={bfit->it}]
    } <- Package fontspec Error: The font "Fira Math Bold" cannot be found.
```

I have tried importing FiraMath-Bold.otf manually and putting it into a `/fonts/FiraMath/` folder and tried switching up the path to `./fonts/FiraMath`or `/fonts/FiraMath`. This changed nothing. But I think Overleaf is supposed to [already have this font installed](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F)?

Since it's a school-provided template for a thesis, it is really important that I don't change the font into something else.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Fira Math Bold `FiraMath-Bold.otf` isn't ready yet: https://github.com/firamath/firamath/issues/9#issuecomment-401530046. In the CTAN release, the bold math variant isn't provided, only the regular one https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/firamath

Comment: You can find bold and other variants in the past releases page, but as the author says, they are not complete, so they may not produce the best output. https://github.com/firamath/firamath/releases/tag/v0.4-beta-3